# (Python graph-tool) graph-tool search using OpenMP? Can finding all paths between a source and target vertex be made parallel?

Tags: python, search, openmp, graph-theory, graph-tool

I am currently using `graph_tool.topology.all_paths` to find all paths between two vertices of a specific length, but the [documentation](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html?highlight=topology#graph_tool.topology.all_paths) doesn't explicitly say what algorithm is used. I assume it is either the breadth-first search (BFS) or Dijkstra’s algorithm like `shortest_path` or `all_shortest_paths`?

My graph is unweighted and directed, so therefore is there a way to make my searches using `all_paths` parallel, and use more cores? I know I have OpenMP turned on using `openmp_enabled()` and that it is set to use all 8 cores that I have.

I have seen that some [algorithms such as the DFS](http://main-discussion-list-for-the-graph-tool-project.982480.n3.nabble.com/Help-regarding-enable-openMP-td4025554.html) cannot be made parallel, but I don't understand why searching through my graph to find all paths up to a certain length is not being done using multiple cores, especially when the [Graph-tool performance comparison page](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance) has benchmarks for shortest path using multiple cores.

Running `graph_tool.topology.all_paths(g, source, target, cutoff=4)` using a basic function:

```
def find_paths_of_length(graph, path_length, start_vertex, end_vertex):
savedpath=[]
for path in graph_tool.topology.all_paths(graph, start_vertex, end_vertex, cutoff=path_length):
    savedpath.append(path)
```

only uses 1 core. Is there any way that this can be done in parallel? My network contains on the order of 50 million vertices and 200 million edges, and the algorithm is O(V+E) according to the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The doc page actually says it uses depth first search to find all the paths. The source code is very simple, and it doesn't handle parallel search.

Comment: @JohnKoch how on earth did I miss that... thank you.